# What's the difference between "quadrature" and "integration"?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

What is the difference between the terms "quadrature" and "integration"?

From what I gather, "quadrature" is the more archaic term for "integration," but I see "quadrature" used frequently in the study of differential equations for when one can solve a differential equation by integration (cf. the phrase: "can be integrated by quadrature"). I've also seen "quadrature" used as a shorthand for "to integrate numerically." Is that what's meant by "quadrature" most frequently today?

Comment: To quote Wikipedia: "*The term numerical quadrature (often abbreviated to quadrature) is more or less a synonym for numerical integration, especially as applied to one-dimensional integrals*"

Comment: Yeah, I personally have strong associations with the "numerical integration" definition. If I'm using the word "quadrature", I'm probably trying to emphasize the fact that a numerical method is involved, or something like that. Otherwise I'd probably just use "integration".

Comment: I think the formulation "can be integrated by quadrature" refers to situation were the solution of an ODE can be reduced to simple integrals (that themselves can not be further reduced symbolically). Something like $y''(x)+xy'(x)=1$, where the integrating factor is simply $e^{x^2/2}$, but the next step involves $\int e^{s^2/2}\,ds$.